# vue init webpack alphalayui strange thing

Tags: vue.js

My environment:

`OS:win10

Vue:2.82

Yarn:0.27.5

Nodejs:8.2.1

Other:Git-bash`

When I first use  `vue init webpack alphalayui`  to build a vue project,I find a strange thing.

It can get my Email-ID,I fell so  amazed,This Email-ID just use in a software which named Foxmail.But I have many Email-ID in this computer.

I want to know how can `vue init` get my Email-ID？

Can someone help me?  Thanks in advance.

`$ vue init webpack alphalayui
? Project name (alphalayui) y
? Project name y
? Project description (A Vue.js project) y
? Project description y
? Author (alphayan <yanyq@sdkej.com>) y
? Author y
? Vue build standalone
? Install vue-router? (Y/n) y
? Install vue-router? Yes
? Use ESLint to lint your code? (Y/n) y
? Use ESLint to lint your code? Yes
? Pick an ESLint preset (Use arrow keys)
? Pick an ESLint preset Standard
? Setup unit tests with Karma + Mocha? (Y/n) y
? Setup unit tests with Karma + Mocha? Yes
? Setup e2e tests with Nightwatch? (Y/n) y
? Setup e2e tests with Nightwatch? Yes`

Comment: Probably from your global git config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
git config --get user.email
```

...and see if it matches.

This is what Vue.init uses in `vue-cli/lib/git-user.js`

```
try {
name = exec('git config --get user.name')
email = exec('git config --get user.email')
} catch (e) {}
```